# Unable to load database on disk

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I got this error when I stop my zookeeper instance and copy all data of zookeeper in other path and change dataDir=/data/zookeeper-data in zookeeper.properties.

```
ERROR Unable to load database on disk (org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer)
java.io.IOException: Unreasonable length = 198238896
at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.checkLength(BinaryInputArchive.java:127)
at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readBuffer(BinaryInputArchive.java:92)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.Util.readTxnBytes(Util.java:233)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.next(FileTxnLog.java:629)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:166)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:223)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:601)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.start(QuorumPeer.java:591)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:164)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:111)
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
```

Seems that some snapshot files under folder /opt/confluent/zookeeper/data/version-2 are corrupted or it doesn't have permission because when I use systemctl start confluent-zookeeper i got thsi error and if I start zookeeper manually I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was from systemd want to write logs in a path that is root:root and it doesn't have permission so when I used chown -R kafka:kafka dir/to/log/path and changed permission, my problem solved.